Nextjs: update cookie in server component
In nextjs(app router), it support server component and we can fetch api in server page component.
The problem is: in most case of application, we need auth user by access/refresh token. We often call refresh token in axios interceptor, then set the cookies.
I know that nextjs can not set cookie in server component, that mean when I call api in server component, if the access token expired, the refresh token action will be called. It can be receive a new access token and complete the request. But the new access token is not updated in cookie, it can be used only once.
Unless new client request is called to update access token in cookies, the refresh token action will be invoked each time call api in server component.
This is not good for an application.
How can I change this behavior?

Have you found any solution?
I have NestJS as backend and NextJS as frontend. And I can't get them to work correctly for a week now regarding cookies.
And the problem is that I just can't move everything to the client component, because the API has to be accessed sometimes from the server side, and if the AccessToken is expired, I have to refresh it with RefreshToken.
But how can I communicate this to the client and refresh the cookie in the browser?
I've seen a couple of solutions via proxy on Router Handler and spoofing in Middleware, but they only work partially.
